# Making *9* congruent triangles from the pieces of a triangle dissection

Tags: mathematics, geometry, dissection

Working on the [making 7 congruent triangles from the pieces of a triangle dissection](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101291/making-7-congruent-triangles-from-the-pieces-of-a-triangle-dissection) question I realized it's possible to do even better! So here it is for extra points:

> Use six lines to cut a triangle into nine congruent triangles.

Comment: I assume that, like the other question, we cannot assume anything about the triangle's shape (it is arbitrary)?

Comment: this one is easier than others

Comment: @bobble Yes, arbitrary triangle

Comment: square numbers are easy.

Comment: Actually, larger number is not always "better" than the smaller number. In this case, the 9 version is apparently (way) more trivial than the 7 version.

Comment: Yes, for sure obtaining 7 is quite a bit more remarkable and surprising.

Answer (score 2):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTqhf.png

Saves some formatting tokens to *not* use a spoiler. It's just an image after all.